# How can I add the path of the file as attributes/fields in a flowfile after parsing?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a `GetFile Processor` parsing some logs using a `ExtractGrok Processor.`  Unfortunately the actual log files themselves contain the same naming convention `request.log` but the path to the logs is different. For example `/var/log/server1/account1/request.log` or `/var/log/server1/account2/request.log.` What I'd like to do is capture anything in `/server1/` and `/account1/` and store them as fields "host" and "account" so I can further partition the records.

I imagine this will look something like `GetFile Processor` ---> `ExtractGrok Processor` and then possibly `PartitionRecord`?  But this is where I'm stuck.  Partition Record would require the directory path to be part of the attributes so I can't include it.  I guess I would need to somehow extract the file path before the `PartitionRecord`?  I'm just not sure exactly where to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`GetFile` should already add the `filename` and `path` attributes to the FlowFiles (see the [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GetFile/index.html)). You could use `UpdateAttribute` to get the values "server1" and "account1" out of the `path` attribute using [Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) (see the `getDelimitedField` function for example).
To add the attribute(s) as fields you can use UpdateRecord with a [GrokReader](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.grok.GrokReader/index.html) and then you don't need the ExtractGrok processor.

It doesn't sound like you need PartitionRecord as I'm presuming each FlowFile's records contain the same value for "host" and/or "account". If that's the case, and you don't need the "host" and "account" fields for anything else, you probably don't need all of the above components and could use UpdateAttribute -> RouteOnAttribute. If that's not the case, then you can use PartitionRecord on whichever other field(s) you want to partition on.

Comment: Hello.  This is where I'm getting stuck.  This is what I have so far:

`GetFIle` ----> `UpdateAttribute` --- `UpdateRecord`

I've successfully added the attributes I needed.  For example:

`host = ${absolute.path:getDelimitedField(4, '/')}`
`account = ${absolute.path:getDelimitedField(5, '/')}`

I can see the new attributes listed.  However, in `UpdateRecord` I'm trying to set the properties as such:

`host: ${host}`
`account: ${account}`

and getting the following error:

`host validated against ${host} is invalid because Property Name is not a valid RecordPath value`

Comment: Instead of a Replacement Value Strategy of `Record Path Value` use `Literal Value` instead, that one allows Expression Language to get at attributes and such.

Comment: Hello.  I'm still running into an issue with this.  On the `UpdateRecord` processor I have replacement value Strategy set to `Literal Value` and I'm still getting that error about `host validated against ${host} is invalid because Property Name is not a valid RecordPath value`

Comment: The Property Name has to be a RecordPath like /host. It's the replacement value that can use Expression Language if Literal Value is set.